# Matrix written in terms of Kronecker delta

Tags: matrices, kronecker-delta

What would be the  matrix form of $P$ defined in equation (1.11) of this [published work](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0503237.pdf), where (I have chosen $n=2$, for simplicity)

$$P_{kl}=\begin{cases}  \delta_{k,2l-1} ~~~ k \le 2\\\\  \delta_{2+k,2l} ~~~ l\le 2 \end{cases}$$

Comment: Try computing the components???

Comment: @K.defaoite what happens when $k, l > 2$ or $k, l < 2$. Eg what's $P_{11}$ or $P_{34}$?

Comment: @okzoomer, that's exactly my point!

Answer (score 1):

From the context of the paper (namely the text below Equation (1.2) that defines $\mathbf R$ and the text below Equation (1.4) defining $\mathbf S$), it seems that the permutation matrix $\mathbf P$ being discussed for which $\mathbf P \mathbf R = \mathbf S$ is the [commutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutation_matrix#Example) $\mathbf P = \mathbf K^{(2,n)}$.

Some examples:

$$n = 2: \mathbf P = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\hline0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]\\
n=3: \mathbf P = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right]\\
n=4: \mathbf P = \left[\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc|cc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right].
$$
With that, I suspect that the intended description of $\mathbf P$ was as follows.
$$
P_{kl} = \begin{cases}
\delta_{k,2l-1} & k \leq n,\\
\delta_{k-n,2l-2} & k > n.
\end{cases}
$$